# how can i print the mySQL sum() in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query and i am asking if i can print the result in `PHP` without saving the result in other table.

```
SELECT SUM(weekly_fees) FROM scout_cabs
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+alias

Comment: Go and study PHP basics. At least you should show some of your efforts in getting the answer. Study some examples there.

For reference visit: www.php.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start by giving it an alias to output:

```
SELECT SUM(`weekly_fees`) AS `total` FROM `scout_cabs`
```

Then you parse it as any normal request via mysql.

```
<?php
$sql    = "SELECT SUM(`weekly_fees`) AS `total` FROM `scout_cabs`";
$run    = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($run);
echo 'The sum of the query is: ' . number_format($result['total']);
```

It may also be worth looking into mysqli_ if you are not already using it, as mysql_ is now deprecated.

Comment: Pleasure is mine. Appreciate the thanks, nonetheless :)